# How to use service mesh type of capabilities on workloads created using buildPack

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a way to use service mesh like Istio etc for workloads created using pivotal buildpacks? 
Is there anything else out of the box that pivotal provides for service mesh capabilities? I wasn't able to find any in pivotal documentation. So wanted to check here and see if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Technology aside, what exactly do you want to do here? PCF has a variety of routing options to get traffic to your apps.

Comment: I want to have a component that can take care of the observability, circuit breaking etc of my pcf services w/o writing monitoring code inside the pcf service

Comment: PCF has Envoy in recent versions (2.4+) but it's only there for ingress routing right now. It doesn't handle service discovery, circuit breaking or observability. Service discovery can be achieved out of the box with container networking on PAS by using DNS, or you can use Eureka/SCS Registry or something like that if you need additionaly functionality. Spring Cloud Gateway offers much of what you're looking for also btw, observability, circuit breaking, and sophisticated routing features. It deploys as a Java/Spring app, but does *not* require your apps to use either of those.